# I have just lost a large amount of data from my firebase firestore DB, is there any way to restore this?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

about ten minutes ago I accidentally called a set function `db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).set({` which reset a lot of data. Does anyone know how I can reset this data? Does firestore backup their data in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no automated backups.  The data is permanently lost, unless you saved it somehow yourself.  People usually do this through the provided [export mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).